# How to retrieve the Json Information from the Provider on Firebase

Tags: android, json, firebase, firebase-authentication, jwt

I was looking on the Firebase SDK and I found that FirebaseUser has a method called 
`getProviderData()`
that we can use to get some information about the provider in case that we are login with Google or Facebook.

But let's say I want to retrieve the `FirstName` and `LastName` instead of `DisplayName` also the `Facebook email` and some specific information that is not implemented on `UserInfo`.

I found a solution for Facebook which is requiring an additional rest call.

```
GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(), new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {
            try {
                jsonResponseMap.put(USER_EMAIL, object.getString("email"));
                jsonResponseMap.put(USER_FIRST_NAME, object.getString("first_name"));
                jsonResponseMap.put(USER_LAST__NAME, object.getString("last_name"));
                listener.onResult(jsonResponseMap);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                listener.onError(e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    });
    Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
    parameters.putString("fields","id, email, first_name, last_name");
    request.setParameters(parameters);
    request.executeAsync();
```

***So the big question is that why make another call when Firebase is providing the json already.***

Researching a little bit I found that Firebase SDK is implementing a class called
`zzf` which implement `UserInfo` and returning the json using

`String getRawUserInfo()`.

Using the debugger I got this json from Google (Facebook has similar format):

Google

```
{
"azp": "86867144690-7vvjul4p96e143413484c5h9e.apps.googleusercontent.com",
"aud": "86813434690-o49lqnvo8c1232315rdrmi1ej9.apps.googleusercontent.com",
"sub": "103026921153548850697",
"email": "Steve.Jhon@gmail.com",
"email_verified": true,
"exp": 1520122390,
"iss": "https://accounts.google.com",
"iat": 1520128790,
"name": "Jhon Steve",
"picture": "https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-4-WnMz5Fqoo/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/AGi4132322313SfRlc412L5tRvZJsOA/s96-c/photo.jpg",
"given_name": "Jhon",
"family_name": "Steve",
"locale": "en"
}
```

**With this information, I want to ask you guys that...
How can I cast the `zzf` class to retrieve the proper raw information from the provider?**

Comment: Those classes with strange names are private to Firebase and are not intended for public use.  Anything about their names and implementation can change at any time.

Comment: So what is your suggestion? 
@DougStevenson Do you think there is a way to create my own UserInfo interface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want additional user info after sign-in/sign-up, you can get it from [AdditionalUserInfo](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/AdditionalUserInfo) on [AuthResult](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/AuthResult).

It provides a `getProfile` API which returns a `map<String, Object>` with all provide related profile info.

Comment: I check this class and yes I like your answer but still do not fix my issue. Becuase I do not have any AuthResult because my app is getting the FirebaseUser from `mAuth.getCurrentUser()`. Do you have any suggestions? I will upvote your answer because when I'm in the login flow it is working properly but my question is related to a FirebaseUser.

Comment: There is no way to get this from the user. Firebase Auth only provides this data in the sign-in result.